# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread error using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium in Spring boot

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, selenium, out-of-memory

We have selenium based web application developed using spring boot. The server is located as VM Instance at google cloud server.

We have a thread base mechanism using **Executor**. Using selenium we open a chrome browser (headless) to perform operation and for each operation we create new thread.

After facing `outOfMemory` error, if we restart cloud instance then within 1 hour it breaks again with the same error.

Please find below the snippet which we used to create a new instance of executor service for each request.

```
executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future<Object> futureDetails = executorService.submit(new Callable<Object>() {

        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {

            Object response = client.getDetails(number);

            return response;
        }
    });

    executorService.shutdown();
```

We have (16 vCPUs, 64 GB memory) server configuration.

Please find below the details of the version.

Spring Boot - 2.0.0.RELEASE

Selenium - 3.9.1

Linux - Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Chrome Driver - 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881)

Google Chrome - 70.0.3538.110

JDK - 1.8.0_232

Please find below resource report using: `ulimit -a`.

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 257648
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 10240
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 257648
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Also, I did check the memory using: `free -m`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          64433        9479       54490         279         463       54132
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Please find below the error stack trace:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) [spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_241]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_241]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_241]
>   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Please help me to understand the issue and root cause of this problem. It would be better if you can suggest a solution as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Selenium tests can definitely become memory hogs, especially if a test run goes for a long time. I wonder if you can pass flags to the test runner to allocate more memory to that Java process. Although that might just delay the OutOfMemory error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789288/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

...implies that JVM was unable to create any new native thread as your system have run *OutOfMemory*

---

### OutOfMemoryError

[Out of Memory](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/126962/out-of-memory-error-message-appears-when-you-have-a-large-number-of-pr) error messages can appear when you attempt to start new programs or you try to use programs that are already running, even though you still have plenty of physical and pagefile memory available. When you run a java program or java application, [os](/questions/tagged/os) allocates some memory to the JVM. JVM divides this memory into two parts. One is the *Stack Memory* and another is the *Heap Memory*. *Stack Memory* is used for execution of methods while *Heap Memory* is used to store the objects. When the heap becomes full, JVM throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

---

### java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](https://javaconceptoftheday.com/stackoverflowerror-vs-outofmemoryerror-in-java/) is thrown when the *Heap Memory* is full and *JVM* is unable to allocate the memory to new objects. As the objects you create in *Java* are stored in the *Heap Memory*, so when ever the objects are no more required, they must be removed from the memory. *Garbage Collector* automatically removes the unwanted objects from the *Heap Memory*. If your objects have live references, garbage collector doesn’t remove them. It removes only those objects which don’t have live references. in this process if at any point of time there is no space left for new objects in the heap memory then JVM will throw `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

---

### This usecase

As per your code trials, you have implemented *Multithreading* using [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to create and use a thread for each request while opening a [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) browsing context.

---

### Multithreading using Selenium

As you mentioned, within 1 hour it breaks agian with the same error, I suspect this due to the fact that [WebDriver is not thread-safe](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-is-webdriver-thread-safe). Having said that, if you can serialize access to the underlying driver instance, you can share a reference in more than one thread. This is not advisable. But you can always instantiate one [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance for each thread.

Ideally the issue of **thread-safety** isn't in your code but in the actual browser bindings. They all assume there will only be one command at a time (e.g. like a real user). But on the other hand you can always instantiate one *WebDriver* instance for each thread which will launch multiple browsing tabs/windows. Till this point it seems your program is perfect.

Now, different *threads* can be run on same *Webdriver*, but then the results of the tests would not be what you expect. The reason behind is, when you use multi-threading to run different tests on different tabs/windows a little bit of thread safety coding is required or else the actions you will perform like `click()` or `send_keys()` will go to the opened tab/window that is currently having the **focus** regardless of the *thread* you expect to be running. Which essentially means all the test will run simultaneously on the same tab/window that has **focus** but **not** on the intended tab/window.

---

### Additional Consideration

However another issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.35*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64**

- You are using *chrome=70.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver vv2.44*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v69-71**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.9.1* which is almost **2** years older.

So there is a clear mismatch between *Selenium Client v3.9.1* , *ChromeDriver v2.35* and the *Chrome Browser v70.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u241](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v80.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.16/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 80.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v80.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.16/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### tl; dr

[How to set memory limit for OOM Killer for chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715649/how-to-set-memory-limit-for-oom-killer-for-chrome/59750032#59750032)

Answer (score 1):

The amount of RAM your server has doesn't matter if you don't allocate that memory to your java process.

If you run your application with (any variant of) `java -jar` command, then add a maximum allowed memory parameter -xmx (check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvm)). If the application runs inside Tomcat (or any application server), you'll need to increase the maximum allowed memory of it (check its parameters and docs).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, too. The problem was that if a submitted or an executed pool thread accessed outside the pool something that requires "too much" memory. If you have thread that does such accesses you should run it as a **REAL** thread, not as a Runnable in an ExecutorService pool.

Comment: We have used Callable in ExecutorService pool.

Comment: It's the same. Callable returns a value while Runnable won't and that is the only different between Callable and Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome storing history starts to take a lot of memory when navigating such a large number of urls because chrome stores the urls in history.

add the incognito argument which does not not store history

```
options.add_argument("--incognito")
```

You can also disable cache:

```
options.add_argument('--disable-cache')
```