# Chrome out of memory in selenium - no error thrown

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium script using Chrome that runs for a very long time.

Eventually, the browser runs out of memory, and I get the "Error code: Out of Memory" page.

The problem is, no error is thrown in Python, so I don't know how to detect when the error has occurred. The code just ends up hanging, usually on a line like

> WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.timeline-events')).click()

It's only until I manually navigate to another page that I get an error like "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event"

I know I can have the script periodically close and reopen the browser, but I'd rather handle the error directly.

EDIT:
Currently, I'm addressing the issue by having the script restart when memory usage gets over 1 GB, but I'd still like to be able to get an actual error thrown.

EDIT 2: I've read over the linked posts and I don't think they address the same issue.

Regarding this post: [How to set memory limit for OOM Killer for chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715649/how-to-set-memory-limit-for-oom-killer-for-chrome)

I'm using Windows. The memory limit seems to be imposed by the browser rather than the operating system.

Regarding this post: [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread error using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium in Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60318473/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread-error-using-chrom)

My issue is that no exception is being thrown (in Python). Instead, the driver just hangs on the line of code posted above and shows the "Error code: Out of Memory" Chrome page, so I can't catch and handle the error.

[image: Chrome out of memory error page]

Running out of memory is kind of expected, since I'm navigating a SPA for a very long time.

Comment: Does Chrome run out of memory if you click manually?

Comment: I assume so. It's not something I want to test, since clicking manually would probably take me a few hours. It looks like it crashes at a around 2 GB memory

Comment: @no_username_ideas Have you find any solution?

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue but with the Java WebDriver

Comment: how can you find out when 'Memory usage gets over 1 GB" ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?